Invalid unicode (byte sequence mismatch) detected in value construction
Getting below error while executing command show tables; or show all tables; in DuckDB
D:\20230422 - BigData\24.DuckDB\data>duckdb
v1.1.2 f680b7d08f
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
D .open D:\20230422 - BigData\24.DuckDB\data\mc.duckdb
D show tables;
Invalid Input Error: Invalid unicode (byte sequence mismatch) detected in value construction
D

I was expecting it show all the tables, tables do exist but getting this error. Not sure if its related to some settings. I am on Windows 11.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That's a bug, if you can make a reproduction of the problem (rebuilding the database from a script) then please file an issue on github (https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues) so it can be fixed

Will do it thanks

Added the issue
https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/14617
